# Custom object filter for a grid column in sencha GXT

Tags: java, gwt, grid, gxt

**Important edit: I added a depth level to the situation to better reflect my problem.**

I have a GXT Grid with a ListStore of a certain type `Foo`. `Foo` happens to have some important object properties, including one of type `Bar`. Type `Bar` consists of two object properties: `fooFoo` of type `FooFoo` and `barBar` of type `Barbar`. These two can be `null` and have a `String` property `description`.

[image: sketch]

I want to use the GXT grid's filtering to filter the `Foo` object records' by their `Bar` value's `FooFoo` or `BarBar` description.

I tried to add a `ValueProvider<Foo, String> barDescription();` to `FooProperties`, resulting in:

```
StringFilter<Foo> barbarFilter = new StringFilter<Foo>(fooProps.barbarDescription());
```

**In which** `Foo#getBarBarDescription()` **is implemented as follows:**

```
public String getBarBarDescription() {
    return this.getBar().getBarBar().getDescription();
}
```

Is there a simple/convenient way to implement this behaviour in GXT? I have not found it.

The implementation I describe above is the one I have tried, but the filters don't show up in the grid at all, no further error messages.

**In response to Colin's answer to the previous version of my question, I have tried the following:**

```
@Path("bar.barbar.description")
ValueProvider<Foo, String> barbarDescription();
```

Hoping for it to call `Foo#getBar().getBarBar().getDescription()`. I suspect the possibility for FooFoo and BarBar to be `null` may be causing issues.

Comment: As per me you are doing it right, and there is no other simple way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have `barDescription()` invoke `getBar().getDescription()` on your `Foo` objects, then try this:

```
public interface FooProperties extends PropertyAccess<Foo> {

  @Path("bar.description")
  ValueProvider<Foo, String> barDescription();

  //...
}
```

The `@Path` annotation works the same here as it does in the editor framework - you can use it to specify the path to the property you want access to. This allows you to skip creating a `getBarDescription()` method in your own `Foo` object.

Another option is to just build your own `ValueProvider` implementation. Using `PropertyAccess` is a way to ask the compiler to do the work for you, but nothing stops you from doing it yourself. In this case, it might look like this:

```
public class FooBarDescriptionValueProvider implements ValueProvider<Foo, String> {
  public String getValue(Foo object) {
    //TOOD consider a object.getBar() null check?
    return object.getBar().getDescription();
  }
  public void setValue(Foo object, String value) {
    object.getBar().setDescription(value);
  }
  public String getPath() {
    return "bar.description";
  }
}
```

Note that this is almost exactly what the PropertyAccess generated version will look like, but it allows you to customize the behavior however you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help Colin. Unfortunately, I forgot to mention one depth level in my original question. It seemed trivial at first, but since using your supplied answer doesn't seem to work (see question), I thought I'd supply the additional info.

Comment: Right, null is an issue (since what should the String be if the Bar was null?) - I'll make a change to the question to try to address some options you have.

Comment: That is, I'll make a change to the *answer*.

Comment: Thanks. How should I go about using the custom provider? I tried `StringFilter<Foo> barbarFilter = new StringFilter<Foo>(new CascadedValueProviders().new FooBarBarBarValueProvider());` to no avail.

Comment: Can you update the question with your valueprovider code? 'no avail' isn't much to comment on. The basic idea will be to just do null checks in the `getValue(Foo)` method. Sorry I haven't updated answer, been a bit busy lately.